Flutter googleapis Speech to text v1 operation returns null response
I'm utilizing the Flutter Google APIs plugin for transcribing speech to text for files exceeding 1 minute in length. The file uploads successfully to the gcs bucket, undergoes transcription, and the resulting text is uploaded back to the bucket in JSON format. However, the operation consistently returns null.
Future<String> transcribe() async {

    final client = await clientViaServiceAccount(
        credentials, [SpeechApi.cloudPlatformScope]);

    SpeechApi speechApi = SpeechApi(client);

    RecognitionAudio audio =
        RecognitionAudio(uri: "gs://audio-translator-ios/anAudioFile.wav");

    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig(
        encoding: "LINEAR16", sampleRateHertz: 48000, languageCode: "en-US");

    LongRunningRecognizeRequest request = LongRunningRecognizeRequest(
        config: config,
        audio: audio,
        outputConfig: TranscriptOutputConfig(
            gcsUri: "gs://audio-translator-ios/myNewJsonFile.json"));

    final operation = await speechApi.speech
        .longrunningrecognize(request)
        .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1000));

    print(operation.response);

    return "Hello";
  }

I was trying to implement this java code in dart:
/**
 * Performs non-blocking speech recognition on remote FLAC file and prints the transcription.
 *
 * @param gcsUri the path to the remote LINEAR16 audio file to transcribe.
 */
public static void asyncRecognizeGcs(String gcsUri) throws Exception {
  // Configure polling algorithm
  SpeechSettings.Builder speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder();
  TimedRetryAlgorithm timedRetryAlgorithm =
      OperationTimedPollAlgorithm.create(
          RetrySettings.newBuilder()
              .setInitialRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(500L))
              .setRetryDelayMultiplier(1.5)
              .setMaxRetryDelay(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
              .setInitialRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
              .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(1.0) // ignored
              .setMaxRpcTimeout(Duration.ZERO) // ignored
              .setTotalTimeout(Duration.ofHours(24L)) // set polling timeout to 24 hours
              .build());
  speechSettings.longRunningRecognizeOperationSettings().setPollingAlgorithm(timedRetryAlgorithm);

  // Instantiates a client with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  try (SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings.build())) {

    // Configure remote file request for FLAC
    RecognitionConfig config =
        RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.FLAC)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .build();
    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

    // Use non-blocking call for getting file transcription
    OperationFuture<LongRunningRecognizeResponse, LongRunningRecognizeMetadata> response =
        speech.longRunningRecognizeAsync(config, audio);
    while (!response.isDone()) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for response...");
      Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.get().getResultsList();

    for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
      // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
      // first (most likely) one here.
      SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
      System.out.printf("Transcription: %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
    }
  }
}

